# MySQL getting percentage of count

Tags: mysql, sql

My Data would like this

```
Name    Similar_Percentage      
A           15
B           20
C           65
```

I want like this

```
Similar_Percentage          count(*)
Less than 20            2
Less than 70            1
```

How to write a query for this.
I know having make this but it show one by one data.

Comment: Are you sure that the expected output is correct? I think the count column should be in reverse order

Comment: In your sample data you have 1 value < 20 and 3 values < 70

Comment: I want count over percentage. Thanks for your ques. @HarshilDoshi

Comment: You are right I don't think about this I want between record 1 between 20 is this and 20 between 70 is that thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: then you should update the question

Answer (score 2):

use case when

```
  select case when Similar_Percentage<20  then 'Less than 20'
            when (Similar_Percentage<70)  then 'Less than 70' end as Percentage,count(*)
    from table group by case when Similar_Percentage<20 then 'Less than 20'
            when (Similar_Percentage<70) then 'Less than 70' end


with cte as (

select  15 as Similar_Percentage
union all
select 20
union all
select 65

)select case when Similar_Percentage<=20  then 'Less than 20'
            when (Similar_Percentage<70)  then 'Less than 70' end as Percentage,count(*)
    from cte group by case when Similar_Percentage<=20 then 'Less than 20'
            when (Similar_Percentage<70) then 'Less than 70' end
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0d2c0192980a19400ac0e9bf17e483ba)

```
Percentage  count(*)
Less than 20    2
Less than 70    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be like following.

```
SELECT 'Less than 20' Percentage, 
       Count(*)       [Count(*)] 
FROM   tablename 
WHERE  similar_percentage <= 20 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Less than 70' Percentage, 
       Count(*)       [Count(*)] 
FROM   tablename 
WHERE  similar_percentage <= 70 
       AND similar_percentage > 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` *expression* in a *derived table* (the subquery) to do the classification. `GROUP BY` its result:

```
select percentage, count(*)
from
(
    select case when Similar_Percentage <= 20 then 'Less than 20'
                when Similar_Percentage <= 70 then 'Less than 70'
                else 'More than 70'
           end as percentage
    from tablename
) dt
group by percentage
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL allows you to use column aliases in the `group by`.  This simplifies the query.

I also recommend an explicit `order by`, so you get the results in the order you want:

```
select (case when Similar_Percentage <= 20  then 'Less than 20'
             when Similar_Percentage < 70 then 'Less than 70'
        end) as Percentage,
       count(*)
from cte
group by Percentage
order by min(Similar_Percentage)
```